# How to access a Feature service hosted on arcgis.com which is shared only with particular groups or organization

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-online, feature-service

In my C# application, I am trying to access a Feature service which is hosted on arcgis.com. The feature service is shared only with a group or organization and is NOT public. How can I access this service in my client code. Here is my client code which throws an exception saying the Authentication Token required. I do have the token but dont know how to use that token to be authenticated to use the service. This same code runs fine for services that are shared as PUBLIC.

```
   IPropertySet sipPS = new PropertySet();
    sipPS.SetProperty("DATABASE", layerUrl);
    IWorkspaceFactory sipWSF = (IWorkspaceFactory)new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureServiceWorkspaceFactory();
    IWorkspace sipWS = sipWSF.Open(sipPS, 0);
    IFeatureWorkspace sipFWS = (IFeatureWorkspace)sipWS;
    IGroupLayer grpLayer = new GroupLayerClass();
    grpLayer.Name = Constants.ArcGISOnlineGroupLayerName;
    IFeatureClass sipFC = sipFWS.OpenFeatureClass("0");
    IFeatureLayer fl = new FeatureLayerClass();
    fl.Name = featureLayerName;
    fl.FeatureClass = sipFC;
    grpLayer.Add(fl as ILayer);
```

Comment: Are you wanting to setup user logins or app logins for your application?  Also, does your application use OAuth 2-based APIs?  Discussion Link: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r30000009z000000

Comment: I am not using OAuth 2-based api for authentication. I am simply generating a token using GenerateToken query by passing in the user's login credentials. After logging in, I published a service on Arcgis.com and shared that with a group. Since the service is not shared as Public, when I myself, or group to which the service is shared, tries to consume this service, "Authentication token required" error appears. I do have the token but I dont know how can I use that token to successfully consume the secure service.

Comment: This has been cross-posted as a direct copy from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429713/how-to-access-a-feature-service-hosted-on-arcgis-com-which-is-shared-only-with-p but has had a bounty added on both sites

Comment: @PolyGeo I posted copy of same question on two places because I need urgent reply. Is that violation of some rule or what?

Comment: The policy on cross-posting to multiple SO/SE sites has been discussed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu  However, by placing a bounty on the same question at both sites, my understanding is that they cannot be closed on either site (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties).  Nevertheless by making potential answerers from both sites aware of the Q&A on the other it may lead to synergies and a faster solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your layerUrl is similar at:
http://services1.arcgis.com/cFi1BRRsYB2fYqCl/arcgis/rest/services/NameService/FeatureServer

Just add the token to Url:
http://services1.arcgis.com/cFi1BRRsYB2fYqCl/arcgis/rest/services/NameService/FeatureServer?token=gGIYjUwXvaO75l1X7LHsgOo2Yueoh1jTGRvrKm7K9ZBE-0TY-EA_Ml7vJtllQK9P2nngX5ciedKgHkjLOEgRSKYR8QhDJMDpWQ09PhTWubNACuFsNIQ3fdlbS6tsPO0h

Comment: I did try to append the token with the layerUrl, but had no luck. I used Fiddler app to see what urls are being generated by the API or the network, but I dont see only `http://services1.arcgis.com/cFi1BRRsYB2fYqCl/arcgis/rest/services/NameService/FeatureServer` being sent over the network even after appending the token with the layerUrl.

Comment: On AGOL, under my contents click on "Open in ArcGIS for Desktop" and start the download of the file item.pitem. In this file you can find the url of the feature layer. Add "?token=<yourtoken>&f=json" to the url and open it in a browser. Tell me what happening.

Comment: I do have the Url of the layer which is `"http://services2.arcgis.com/js0B5yfJ0ZQG/arcgis/rest/services/TxsUltural/FeatureServer` and I also have the token generated. lets assume token is `abc112asdfkljznxc123123lkjkj23klj` so complete url is like `"http://services2.arcgis.com/js0B5yfJ0ZQG/arcgis/rest/services/TxsUltural/FeatureServer?token=abc112asdfkljznxc123123lkdfkj23klj"`
And I have also tried with individual sublayers like 
`url:"http://services2.arcgis.com/js0BC5yf1J0Z4Q5G/arcgis/rest/services/texas_cultural/FeatureServer/1?token=abc112asdfkljznxc123123lkjadfkj23klj"` but no luck

Comment: I am able to view the layer in browser using above url and token. Its just that I am getting `Token Authentication required` exception when I use it in code that is posted in original Question :)

Comment: total stab in dark - might the PropertySet have an undocumented TOKEN property?

Comment: Try this:

ArcGISSingleSignon ss = new ArcGISSingleSignon();
string bsToken = "";
string bsReferer = "";
string bsUser = "";
ss.GetToken(0, ref bsToken, ref bsReferer, 60, ref bsUser);
UID pUID = new UID();
pUID.Value = "ESRI_MapCenter_MapCenterButton";
ICommandItem cmd = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(pUID, false, false);
cmd.Execute();

ESRI_MapCenter_MapCenterButton is the Dialog to "Add Data from ArcGIS Online" and display the layers that can be loaded.

Comment: @lele3p
with this code when I execute `pUID.Value = "ESRI_MapCenter_MapCenterButton"` I get exception that "value does not fall with in the expected range"

Comment: WQad, since you can see the layers from a browser when you use either of the URL+token methods, will you try logging into ArcGIS Online from ArcGIS for Desktop as the same username then add the layer to the TOC by-hand?  If so, what is your result?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link, seems to be that you do have some proxy issue. For accessing a secured services you need to have username and password and just write a code where token is generated at run time and you just need to append it properly

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0048000000sv000000

Comment: I do have the user name, password and have generated the token using `generateToken` query. Just not able to retrieve the secure services that I have published.

Answer (score 1):

This [example post](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/76586#post354261) from the GeoNet forum is javascript-based, but it essentially accomplishes what you want to happen.

However, for the case of ESRI's 'ArcObjects for .Net' API (which we can tell you are using based on the Namespaces) you should implement the IArcGISSingleSignon.GetToken method. This object's method will sign on a user to ArcGIS Online (AGOL) and return a token.  The workspace factory and the featureclass object definitions do not require the token, but the signon must occur before accessing secured AGOL feature services.

Lastly, just as an API point, IWorkspaceFactory is obsolete and [IWorkspaceFactory2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000m9z000000) is now the preferred interface object.--the signatures didn't change but the backend implementations did.

Please post to confirm your C# add-in correctly connects to AGOL once you implement single-signon tokens using the GetToken method.

Comment: I did try `IArcGISSingleSignOn.GetToken' and got the token generated after inputting my credentials to the sign in dialog that appears. Afterwards executed the same code as in the question, but still getting the same exception "Authentication token required".